# MySQL change datadir, problem with mysqld.sock

Tags: mysql, database

I tried to change the database directory, datadir, I did the following steps.
My machine: Laptop Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

All Ok, I can create databases, tables, all ok.
Change the datadir:

```
1) $ /etc/init.d/mysql stop
2) $ cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql /new_path
3) $ rm /new_path                      (this only remove files unnecessary)
4) $ gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Change the "datadir = var/lib/mysql" to the new path.

```
5) $ gedit /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Change the "/var/lib/mysql" to the new lines with "/new_path/mysql"

```
6) $ /etc/init.d/apparmor reload
7) $ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
8) $ service mysql status     (is Ok)
```

The error is the following.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

I tried to change the permissions in /new_path/mysql and didn't work.

I tried to copy only the databases (not all files in mysql dir) and it didn't work

I saw in other forum that I have to change the /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld  the following

```
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid w,
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,
```

Replace "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld" by "/{,var/}run/mysqld/mysqld" but in my case it was with "/{,var/}run/mysqld/mysqld" by default.

Please I need help, I have 2 weeks with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the steps here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/224/how-to-i-move-mysql-data-files-onto-different-partition ?

Comment: Can you look in /var/log/mysql/* and see if there is anything relevant in there, and maybe add it to your question?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

cd `/var/lib/`

```
tar -cf - mysql | (cd /new_path ; tar -xvf -)
```

then (because it's always a good idea) make a back up.

```
 mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.old
```

then a symlink

```
 ln -s /new_path/mysql/ /var/lib
```

in that case you dont need to touch the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work for me I needed to modify the mysql files in **/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld**. The symbolic link was not good enough for some reason. Perhaps the link did not exist before apparmor was ran. So I did the following:

```
nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

and changed

```
  #/var/lib/mysql/ r,
  #/var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
  /mysql/mysql/ r,
  /mysql/mysql/** rwk,
```

where /mysql was my mount point for all of my mysql data repository (an SSD drive).

I got the clue from a post by walli in:
[Re: MySQL ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=804021&page=5)

I was lucky to find the solution to this problem. It was an all-nighter for me to find the solution. I hope this helps you. **It would be a good idea to post a note directly in the my.cnf file about this issue**. I just dont know who to send it to.