# mysql: unrecognized service (apparmor)

Tags: mysql, apparmor

Mysql was working, then I tried to move the MySql database directory as [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224/how-to-i-move-mysql-data-files-onto-different-partition) which I already successfully used several times, but this time something went wrong and I got the error:

```
$ mysql  
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

so I re-installed mysql (several times as I kept getting that error), mainly with the following commands:

```
# ** uninstall:
sudo su
rm -r /var/lib/mysql # delete the database
aptitude remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean

# ** reinstall
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
apt-get update
```

The disk is not full and I think think the problem is that at some point somehow I managed to get `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` deleted and now I have the previous problem and also

```
$ service mysql status
mysql: unrecognized service
```

The disk is not full and if I reinstall mysql the file is not added. So, thanks to @AbrahamVanHelpsing I got the file from source, but the problem stills. Any ideas?

Thanks

## Edit

`aa-status` did not mention mysql but it does now that I put the file that was missing.

## Another edit

I can access mysql by running `sudo mysqld` and then `mysql` from another terminal, I still hope to register mysql in apparmor though

Comment: What do you see when you run `sudo aa-status`? Is there any reference to mysql in the output? And, `sudo apt-get apparmor-profiles` *may* have something for mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the new MySQL location to apparmor alias.

To add it, simply type

`sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias`

And add this to the end of the file

```
/your/new/data/dir -> /var/lib/mysql
```

Note: you may see the ubuntu buit-in manual in the file

And type

```
sudo invoke-rc.d apparmor reload
```

Then it should work

Or a simpler solution

Remove AppAmor

```
sudo apt-get purge apparmor
```

Comment: I don't really think anyone wants to remove apparmor! I'll try that once at home, thanks by now!

Comment: Please don't suggest apparmor be removed!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use mysql then you can use docker container. It will remain isolated.

url:- `https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/`